# redis reliable queue pattern

Tags: redis, message-queue

http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush

"RPOPLPUSH (or BRPOPLPUSH for the blocking variant) offers a way to avoid this problem: the consumer fetches the message and at the same time pushes it into a processing list. It will use the LREM command in order to remove the message from the processing list once the message has been processed."

This reliable queue pattern is recommended. The key here is removing item from queue unless process finishes. But my biggest confusion is why processing queue is needed here? The same goal could be achieved by keeping only one queue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs when you have more than one tasks accessing the queue, which is likely going to be the case. If you leave it on the queue, you risk another task picking it up and duplicating the message. To solve this and have reliability, you use RPOPLPUSH, this takes the message off the main queue, pushes it onto a secondary queue and gives the task the message to do whatever it is that the task wants to do. Now a secondary task may come along and can access the main queue without concern for duplication.

Finally, when the first task completes it can LREM and remove the message from the processing queue, thus completing its job. This process is repeated by any task and you could implement a single processing queue for all tasks, or a separate processing queue for each task, this will depend on your use case.